# How to calculate an area enclosed by two parametric curves?

Tags: definite-integrals, area, parametric, curves, plane-curves

I know the area under the curve given by parametric equations$x=f(t),y=g(t),\alpha\leq t\leq \beta$ is given by$$A=\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}g(t)f'(t)dt$$

That is in $\int_{a}^{b}ydx$ we have substituted $y=g(t) \ and\  x=f(t)$ and apply appropriate limits and we get the above formula.

**But my main question arises now, is it possible to calculate an area enclosed by two parametric curves without changing them into cartesian or polar etc coordinates?**

*For example:*
Calculate an area enclosed between the asteroid and the circle.

$y=sin^{3}t,\ x=cos^{3}t$           $\ \  \\  \    \ $        ...**(1)**

$y=sint,\ x=cost$                     $ \ \  \\  \    \ $                              ...**(2)**

Graph of these curve are as follows[image]

**My try**

Am I on the correct way or not.

As we know the area between the two curve is given by $\int_{a}^{b} |f _{1}(x)-f_{2}(x)|dx$ so here we can try $|sint-sin^{3}t|$. But main problem occurs for $dx$ what we have to use it for $x$ that is either $x=x=cos^{3}t \ or \ x=cost$.

Can any one help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint :}$

Use relation 
$$
y^{2/3}+x^{2/3}=1 \qquad \text{for asteroid} \implies y_1(x)=\cdots
$$
and
$$
y^2+x^2 =1 \qquad \text{for circle} \implies y_2(x)=\cdots
$$
So you can integrate directly for first quadrant without worried much about $dx$. If you want to do it by integrate over $t$, you should do them separately to avoid confusion. That is
$$
A = \Big|\int_0^1 y_1 dx - \int_0^1 y_2 dx\Big| = \Big|\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \sin^3 t \, d (\cos^3 t) - \int_{s_0}^{s_1} \sin s \, d(\cos s) \Big|
$$
for area in the first quadrant.

Comment: I already knew it. As I mentioned in my post that without changing into catersian etc. Can we evaluate it by parametric equations or not?

Comment: Ops. I didnt see that. But you can. Let me fix.